# How to get all metes and bounds instead of just one?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm trying to pull all of the metes and bounds from a PDF document. Right now I have a code that reads the pdf and pulls in all the text. After it pulls in all the text I want it to pull out only the metes and bounds within the legal. The code works, however, it only pulls in one of them instead of all of them.

This is the code I run after extracting the text:

```
 import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path, poppler_path, tesseract_path):
    # set the path to the tesseract executable
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = tesseract_path

    # convert PDF to image
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_path, poppler_path=poppler_path)

    # loop through each page and extract text
    extracted_text = ""
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        # save the image temporarily
        image_path = f'temp_image_{i}.png'
        image.save(image_path)

        # extract text from the image
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_path)

        # append the extracted text
        extracted_text += text

        # remove the temporary image file
        os.remove(image_path)

    # extract the metes and bounds section
    metes_and_bounds = find_metes_and_bounds(extracted_text)

    return metes_and_bounds

pdf_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\U0102639.pdf'
poppler_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\poppler-0.68.0\bin'
tesseract_path = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

metes_and_bounds = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path, poppler_path, tesseract_path)

print(metes_and_bounds)
```

This is the output 00°12'55" W 658.37

Here is the full legal:

> Commence at a 3/8" rebar marking the northwest corner of the Northeast
> Quarter (NE1/4) of the Southwest Quarter (SW1/4) of Section 14,
> Township 13 South, Range 5 East; and from thence run $ 00°12'55" W for
> a distance of 658.37 feet to a capped rebar found (20125); thence run
> S 89°45'44" E for a distance of 1284.98 feet to an axle found on the
> northwest right of way of Lister Ferry Road (60' ROW); thence deflect
> left and run northeasterly along said right of way a chord distance of
> 282.52 feet to a capped rebar found (20125); thence leaving said right of way, run N 73°54'04" W for a distance of 1432.68 feet, more or
> less, to the point of beginning; SAVE AND EXCEPT the following portion
> thereof: Commence at a 3/8" rebar marking the northwest corner of the
> Northeast Quarter (NE1/4) of the Southwest Quarter (SW1/4) of Section
> 14, Township 13 South, Range 5 East; and from thence run § 00°12'55" W
> for a distance of 658.37 feet to a capped rebar found (20125); thence
> run S 89°45'44" E for a distance of 1284.98 feet to an axle found on
> the northwest right of way of Lister Ferry Road (60! ROW), and which
> point is the point of beginning of the parcel described herein; thence
> from said point of beginning, deflect 180 and run N 89°45'54" W a
> distance of 200 feet to a point; thence deflect right and run N
> 11°35'44" Wa distance of 75 feet to a point; thence deflect right and
> run in a southeasterly the direction in a straight line to the point
> of beginning of said excepted parcel.

Comment: Try to use a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help others answer your question a lot faster. Thanks!

Comment: Not a lot of code here not sure how more minimum I can get and still show the output... What would you use besides tesseract? I get the output results as I want, its not giving me all of the metes and bounds.

Comment: This capped rebar found (20125) is just an error on the OCR. Every legal will be different but they will all have a direction N-S-E-W, degrees, minutes, seconds and feet. That is the data I need pulled out S 89°45'44" E 284.98

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your exact aim is but the best approach is probably to separate each Phrase; and filter for the best average output from OCR where several errors have been added. This is about as good as I can suggest, but as I don't know regex or Python you will need to apply as per their syntax

either `([N|S|§|$][^a-zA-Z]*[E|W])|(of\s\d+.*eet)` or more visually grouped per below

`([N|S|§|$][^a-zA-Z]*[E|W])(.*)(of\s\d+.*eet)|(of\s\d+.*eet)`

[image]

[image]